# How to store array value in sqlite in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite

I'm getting error to store array value in database. My last array value is stored in database. I thought the counter was proper. Where in this code did I do wrong? I'm creating a counter in the database to store array values.
i got this error message Save Error: library routine called out of sequence
on this line ############

```
-(BOOL)Add
{


    NSString *filePath = [BaseModal getDBPath];
    NSLog(@"this check:%@",filePath);
    sqlite3 *database;

    if(sqlite3_open([filePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
        const char *sqlStatement = "insert into Name(name,Date,CDate,Attach form,data) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
        sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)

        {
            NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
            [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
            NSString* date = [dateFormat stringFromDate:Date];
            NSString* cdate = [dateFormat stringFromDate:Cdate];

            sqlite3_bind_text( compiledStatement, 1, [name UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement, 2, [date UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);           
            sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement, 3, [cdate UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            //sqlite3_bind_text( compiledStatement, 4, [UDate UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            sqlite3_bind_int(compiledStatement, 4, Attach form);
            sqlite3_bind_text( compiledStatement, 5, [data UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);  
            //sqlite3_bind_int(compiledStatement, 6, i);

        }
        if(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) != SQLITE_DONE ) {
            NSLog( @"Save Error: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
            sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
            sqlite3_close(database);
            return FALSE;
        }
        else {
            TaskId=sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(database);
            sqlite3_reset(compiledStatement);
            //sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);

            //now insert into name table
            const char *sqlStatement3 = "insert into TeaInfo(TitleId,TeaId) VALUES (?,?)";
            sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement3;
            if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement3, -1, &compiledStatement3, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)    {
                sqlite3_bind_int(compiledStatement3, 1, TitleId);

                for(int counter=0;counter<[self.Tea count];counter++)//***************************
                {
                    Teaclass *teaInfo=(Teaclass*)[self.Teas objectAtIndex:counter];
                    sqlite3_bind_int( compiledStatement3, 2, teaInfo. TeaId);
                }
                    if(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement3) != SQLITE_DONE )//############# 
                    {
                        NSLog( @"Save Error: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database) );
                        //return FALSE;
                    }                   
                //}             

            }

            return TRUE;
        }       

    }
    return TRUE;

}
```

Comment: Please clarify in which step did you receive the error, and what the error message is.

Comment: Let us know where exactly you are facing error...

Comment: kiran i am facing error on counter the array please check i am doing wrong something bec in database it insert only last array value why not all what the mistak

Comment: Not an answer, but have you though about using FMDB. Is will make the SQL usage much more easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved problem in `if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement3, -1, &compiledStatement3, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)`this line I have to write in for loop then row is inserted properly.

Answer (score 1):

Try the code below,

```
const char *sqlStatement3 = "insert into TeaInfo(TitleId,TeaId) VALUES (\"VALUE1\",\"VALUE2\)";
```